# apache zeppelin is started but there is connection error in localhost:8080

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

after successfully build apache zepellin  on Ubuntu 14, I start zeppelin and it says successfully started but when I go to localhost:8080 Firefox shows unable to connect error like it didn't started but when I check Zeppelin status from terminal it says running and also I just copied config files templates so the config files are the default

### update

changed the port to 8090 , here is the config file , but no change in result

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>


<configuration>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.server.addr</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  <description>Server address</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.server.port</name>
  <value>8090</value>
  <description>Server port. port+1 is used for web socket.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.websocket.addr</name>
  <value>0.0.0.0</value>
  <description>Testing websocket address</description>
</property>

<!-- If the port value is negative, then it'll default to the server
     port + 1.
  -->
<property>
  <name>zeppelin.websocket.port</name>
  <value>-1</value>
  <description>Testing websocket port</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.notebook.dir</name>
  <value>notebook</value>
  <description>path or URI for notebook persist</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.notebook.storage</name>
  <value>org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.VFSNotebookRepo</value>
  <description>notebook persistence layer implementation</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.interpreter.dir</name>
  <value>interpreter</value>
  <description>Interpreter implementation base directory</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.interpreters</name>
  <value>org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter,org.apache.zeppelin.spark.PySparkInterpreter,org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkSqlInterpreter,org.apache.zeppelin.spark.DepInterpreter,org.apache.zeppelin.markdown.Markdown,org.apache.zeppelin.angular.AngularInterpreter,org.apache.zeppelin.shell.ShellInterpreter,org.apache.zeppelin.hive.HiveInterpreter,org.apache.zeppelin.tajo.TajoInterpreter,org.apache.zeppelin.flink.FlinkInterpreter,org.apache.zeppelin.ignite.IgniteInterpreter,org.apache.zeppelin.ignite.IgniteSqlInterpreter</value>
  <description>Comma separated interpreter configurations. First interpreter become a default</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.ssl</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>Should SSL be used by the servers?</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.ssl.client.auth</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>Should client authentication be used for SSL connections?</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.ssl.keystore.path</name>
  <value>keystore</value>
  <description>Path to keystore relative to Zeppelin configuration directory</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.ssl.keystore.type</name>
  <value>JKS</value>
  <description>The format of the given keystore (e.g. JKS or PKCS12)</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.ssl.keystore.password</name>
  <value>change me</value>
  <description>Keystore password. Can be obfuscated by the Jetty Password tool</description>
</property>

<!--
<property>
  <name>zeppelin.ssl.key.manager.password</name>
  <value>change me</value>
  <description>Key Manager password. Defaults to keystore password. Can be obfuscated.</description>
</property>
-->

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.ssl.truststore.path</name>
  <value>truststore</value>
  <description>Path to truststore relative to Zeppelin configuration directory. Defaults to the keystore path</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.ssl.truststore.type</name>
  <value>JKS</value>
  <description>The format of the given truststore (e.g. JKS or PKCS12). Defaults to the same type as the keystore type</description>
</property>

<!--
<property>
  <name>zeppelin.ssl.truststore.password</name>
  <value>change me</value>
  <description>Truststore password. Can be obfuscated by the Jetty Password tool. Defaults to the keystore password</description>
</property>
-->

</configuration>
```

and here are the ports which are in listening state after zeppelin is started

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8091                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::9001                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

and `Zeppelin is running                                        [  OK  ]`
 is the response I get when I run command `bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh status`

Comment: usually that port is used by your spark master if you are running it in standalone mode with default conf. check your ports, zeppelin logs and update your question. Your question is not salvageable with the few given information

Comment: edited the question with more info and changed the port , didn't changed anything else in `zeppelin-site.xml` but still nothing

Comment: well then zeppelin is at port 8091! try to connect to localhost:8091

Comment: when I put `localhost:8091` in firefox afer pressing enter it suddenly chages to  `http://www.localhost.com:8091` then it shows server not found page the same doesn't happen for `localhost:8090` and why should it be on `8091` when it suppose to be on `8090`

Comment: because it's not www.localhost.com! try 127.0.0.1:8091/

Comment: tested that too it said `The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81411/discussion-between-eliasah-and-user2320445).

Answer (score 6):

Check if you can reach it at `127.0.0.1:8080`. This works for me, while `localhost:8080` also is not reachable.

Answer (score 5):

Also check other Zeppelin files, like `interpreter.json` and the notebook files. They might have saved config values that are overriding what you are setting in `configuration.xsl`.

I had a similar problem, mostly with the MASTER setting, but also with the port. I specified new values, but Zeppelin was ignoring them. I eventually discovered that Zeppelin had taken the value of the environment variable `MASTER`, and unknown to me, saved it into the `interpreter.json` file. You might try editing that file, or recreating your Zeppelin *Interpreters*.

In my case, I decided not to mess with that, just did a complete reinstalling of Zeppelin to ensure a clean slat.  Then added the following lines to the `zeppelin-env.sh` file before starting:

```
export MASTER=local[*]
export ZEPPELIN_PORT=8088
```

That worked.

Answer (score 0):

In zeppelin-site.xml file conf should be like as you did, add right spark master address in zeppelin-env.sh and interpreter.json file.

you can copy spark master address from spark-master log file.
I did like this and running fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The solution that worked for me was to add the ip and domain name in etc/hosts. 
If you go to logs folder where zeppelin is installed you may find more information. For me, that helped. The logs showed an "Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException... Temporary failure in name resolution".

Adding the host name in etc/hosts solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, spark and zeppelin version was conflicted. My zeppelin was not support spark 2.2.0(It's possible from new version : check outhttps://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2768). If someone has no errors on zeppelin log and can't get in localhost, check your zeppelin supports your spark version.