# Apache Zepplin 0.8 installed but connection error in localhost:8080

Tags: hadoop, apache-zeppelin

On my host machine I had Apache Zeppelin 0.7.3 which I wanted to upgrade to 0.8.0.
After downloading Zeppelin 0.8 and installing it on my host I was able to start successfully zeppelin with systemctl.

To this point everything seems correct but http://localhost:8080/ gives me "Website not reachable". Zeppelin is also not listening to port 8080 as I can see with **lsof -i -P -n**.
I tried also all suggestion [on this stackoverflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024841/apache-zeppelin-is-started-but-there-is-connection-error-in-localhost8080) but no suggestion there could solve my problem.

Below find my configurations to the zeppelin conf-files:

**zeppelin-env.sh:**
I added following lines to zeppelin-env.sh:

- export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161
- export SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera2-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.316101/lib/spark2/
- export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf/
- export MASTER=yarn-client
- export ZEPPELIN_PORT=8080

**zeppelin-site.xml:** zeppelin.server.port set to **8080**

**zeppelin status**
[image]

**zeppelin ports**
In this screenshot it is clear that zeppelin is not listening to port 8080
[image]

I can also see no problems in the zeppelin logs.
Any suggestions for me?

Comment: I found out that zeppelin listens to port 8080 exactly after 1 hour after I started zeppelin with systemctl. Can someone explain this behavior?